# Merge different paths into one - inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have 3 adjacent rectangle as shown belown. I have 2 simple questions based on that.

1 - In this picture, selected area has 2 paths on top of each other. how i can make them one?

[image]

2 - In same picture again, selected area has 3 different paths.They just touching each other by a node. How i can make them one single path again?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this question is ambiquous. Nobody knows do you want closed paths, separate line segments or folded single paths which are technically one but go forth and back several times between the same nodes. One solution to the written question would be "draw a new shape which has separate line segments" , but maybe you want something else. Please, try to reveal something of your intentions

Comment: for instance in first picture selected area has 2 paths and 4 nodes. 1path and 2 nodes belongs to left rectangle while other path and other 2 nodes belongs to right rectangle. i want to make it just 1 path which belongs to right and left rectangles at the same time. i dont think its that complicated.

Comment: It's complicated because it's based on private thinking. Every rectangle has its own nodes and line segments. You must have open paths - a rectangle with only three sides, one is left out, because in the same place there's already a line segment. You could draw the shape as a single open path - no overlaps, only crossings.

Comment: It's not possible, vectors don't work like that. You can't join a node from one path to another node or segment in the middle of a path.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - I don't think so.  In any case it's not really clear to me what the OP wants or is actually trying to achieve in the long run, but from the diagrams it looks like they are trying to join an end node from one path to the middle of another path. Perhaps I'm wrong . . . ?

Comment: This is an old bug report, but maybe you can gain something from the attached python extension: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/521988/comments/35

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, you want something not possible. Every shape has it own nodes and stroke. In addition a path, where a single node has 3 or more branches, is nonexistent in Inkscape.

You must have open paths to avoid overlaps. Examples; parts are moved  a little apart:

[image]

The black version has separate shapes. The green version is a single open path

You can draw everything easily with the pen if you have a grid for snapping or if you use point snaps and have a locked copy of your original attempt in the bottom.

If you want handle the black version as one, you can make a group or combine the paths. The latter is mostly used to make holes to closed shapes, but one can also make a combined path which keeps several non-overlapping paths together.

Comment: in your first example(black one), can you tell me how iam gonna understand i've reached first shape's height while drawing second shape?

Comment: @kai you can make a model  with rectangles, drag it to the bottom in the objects panel and lock it to keep it in its place and draw with the pen (=clicking) having snap to nodes ON. As well you can draw the mid part at first over the left part and move the shape when at least the height is ok. You can also split the needed parts from a copy of the left part. Then scale horizontally and place.